# Scroll link to another page's section smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have `index.php` which has different sections like `top`,`service`,`aboutus` and`contactus` .I have my `header.php` in includes folder and I include it to each and every files separately.I added jquery for smooth scroll for sections.

Now I have `gallery.php` which has the same header.Now I want to call each and every section from gallery to index/section. So I changed the `href="#service"` to `href=index.php#service`.Now it works from both index and gallery pages.

**Problem:**
The smooth scroll on works if I call the section from `index.php`. When I call a section from `gallery.php` it just load the upper part of `index.php` and suddenly moves to the called section.I want it to move smoothly.How can I make it happen?

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

Comment: You have some javascript code conflict. you have to debug into your code.

Comment: I added my jquery code here.Please check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code look good but you have to make **footer.php** and call function from **footer.php** so that your problem will reslove.

As i use we have to call all jquery related things from footer but its depend on your requirements so in that case you can call from **footer.php**

Comment: You mean do I have to add the **script file** at the footer or the **hyperlinks**?

Comment: I have the same links in the footer.It is also working like the header does.